# How can I access a string from another class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string, listbox

I got two scenes (windows), "MainWindow.xaml.cs" and "SecondaryWindow.xaml.cs". I also have one class "Control.cs".

Im trying to declare 2 different `List<string>`, and 2 `public string` in my Control.cs class. 
It looks like this.

```
class Control
    {

    }
    public class MyControl
    {
        List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
        List<string> DescriptionList = new List<string>();

        public string Name {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; }
        }

        public string Description {
        get { return Description; }
        set { Description = value; }
        }
    }
```

I want to access the different strings from Control.cs in my SecondWindow.xaml.cs class so that i can give them each a value from 2 textboxes in SecondWindow.

After this i want the string `Name` to save to `NameList` and string `Description` to `DescriptionList`.

Then I will send `Name` to a ListBox in "MainWindow" where i think it could be added something like this..?

```
 private void Button_SaveAndReturn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var main = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

            if (Example.Name != "" && Example.Description != "")
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                main.listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1} ", Example.name, now));
                this.Close();

            }
```

Im trying my best to give out as much details as i can, tell me if there is anything else you need! Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is my **Control** class:

```
class Control
    {
        List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
        List<string> DescriptionList = new List<string>();

        public static string Name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }

        public static string Description
        {
            get { return Description; }
            set { Description = value; }
        }
    }
```

And my **main** class

```
 private void Button_SaveAndReturn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            { 
                List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
                List<string> descriptionList = new List<string>();

                var name = Control.Name;
                var desc = Control.Description;
                var main = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

                if (name != "" && desc !="")
                {
                    nameList.Add(name);
                    descriptionList.Add(desc);
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    main.listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1} ", name, now));
                    this.Close();

                }
            else if (name== "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name", "Name Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                this.NameInput.Focus();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Please enter some text", "Text Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                this.TextInput.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: Start learning MVVM pattern. Believe me, it makes what you want more easy.

Comment: Reformat your code in the question. What is your `Example`? Your `Control` class is completely empty, is that how ti should be?

Comment: @S.Akbari I know that MVVM Should be alot better for this sort of application. But it shouldn't have been this hard - as i think it is.

Comment: @m.rogalski I meant example as in  if (Control.Name != "" && Control.Description != "") that it should do the following. So that if the textbox fields for name and description have any information it should do the following. 
Im not sure what to put in there.. Damn i feel ashamed, to be this lost.

Comment: But your `Control` class is empty, it has no fields, methods, properties nothing. So even if you would be about using `Control.Name` there's no such property inside of `Control`.

Comment: cant I be using MyControl.Name then? Or would there be any important difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using WPF's MVVM capabilities? If you are, you can declare those lists and variables in a viewmodel common to all those classes; otherwise just mark all those properties as static so you can access them from the other classes like: MyControl.Name, MyControl.Description, etc...

Comment: Will it work by making them static? I have seen some examples of it but didn't get it to work really.

Comment: It will. Give it a try. Put "public static" before the list declarations and try to do MyControl.NameList.Add("a name") in one of the windows. As soon as you go to the other window, the variable should still hold its value.

Comment: Alright! I've got acces to MyControl.name. but would i be able to give MyControl.Name a value by typing into a textbox and passing the value to MyControl.Name? 
Also thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a problem. You can always handle the TextChanged event on the textbox and assign the value there or have a button and assign the value on the button's click event handler.

Comment: Alright, I've modified it a bit now and done the following placed the strings and lists inside Class Control instead of public class MyControl.

With the following code:

 if (Control.Name != "" && Control.Description !="")
            {
                nameList.Add(Control.Name);
                descriptionList.Add(Control.Description);
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                main.listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1} ", 
Control.Name, now));

When i run it i get error:
The maximum number of stack frames supported by visual studio has been exceeded.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the latest version of your code so that I can have the full picture?

Comment: Here you go, updated version. Update it as i added Else if statement just for clarity.

Comment: I just noted that i have 2 lists for the same purpose. Which would you recommend i remove? The one in Control class or Main class? It should save the values so that i can later access them by SelectedItem in ListBox.

Comment: Well, the code looks simple enough and I don´t think that it is the cause of that exception. Can you post the exception's StackTrace?

Comment: You should keep the ones in the Control class.

Comment: Would it be smart to make the NameList in control Static so that i can access it in MainWindow? And maybe make a: 

var ListOfNames= Control.NameList;  

as an example? I will try to post the correct stackTrace, just a second.

$exception {The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time.} System.StackOverflowException 

The error is at Control class, get{return Name;}

Comment: No tips for this Martin?

Comment: Yes. You can make those two properties static as well. No need to create separate variables in the rest of the code since you can assign values to them directly. The exception happens because in the getter you're trying to return the same property, causing an infinite loop. Your property should look like this instead: `public static string Name { get; set; } `

Answer (score 1):

I would use **Prism** for that.

Here is an example:

**Class which will raise the event:**

```
public class PublisherClass
{
    public void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Publish(name);
    }
}
```

**Two classes will subscribe to this event:**

```
public class SubscriberClass1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SubscriberClass1()
    {
        Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);
    }

    private void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

**and**

```
public class SubscriberClass2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SubscriberClass2()
    {
        Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);
    }

    private void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

**EventAggregator which is part of Prism.Events resides here:**

```
public class Utility
{
    public static EventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }

    static Utility()
    {
        EventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
    }
}
```

**And the event is simply defined like this:**

```
public class UpdateNameEvent : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}
```

**Now give it a try:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PublisherClass publisher = new PublisherClass();
    SubscriberClass1 subscriber1 = new SubscriberClass1();
    SubscriberClass2 subscriber2 = new SubscriberClass2();
    publisher.UpdateName("Name1");

    Console.WriteLine(subscriber1.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(subscriber2.Name);
}
```

For this example i am using a string as parameter but you can replace that according to your needs. 
Be it an MVVM approach or any other pattern, you can easily implement this kind of communication.

Install Prism.Core with the help of Nuget and you will get the reference to Prism dll.

That's about it.